# Why isn't this changing the color of the label?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to change the label color in sprite kit with this:

```
    score = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Arial")
    score.text = "Test/(addScore)"
    score.color = SKColor.blackColor()
    score.fontSize = 20
    score.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    addChild(score)
```

But it still is white. Any ideas on why its not black?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `color` property of SKLabelNode is the label's **blend** color. If you want to change the font color you should use the `fontColor` property:

```
score.fontColor = SKColor.blackColor()
```

**Documentation:**
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKLabelNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKLabelNode/fontColor